# Getter returning NaN

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, getter

I've been having some strange problems with the collision code of a game I'm making, and I've been able to trace it down to this: the getters of my properties are returning NaN, instead of an actual number.

Here are the declarations of the properties, at the top of the class:

```
private var _top:Number;
private var _bottom:Number;
private var _left:Number;
private var _right:Number;
```

And here are the getters:

```
public function get top():Number 
{
    return _top;
}

public function get bottom():Number 
{
    return _bottom;
}

public function get left():Number 
{
    return _left;
}

public function get right():Number 
{
    return _right;
}
```

The values become generated by calling the public function `setSides(tileSize:Number)` of a class instance (the values depending on the `tileSize` parameter). After I've run that, I run a trace which gets the values using the getters, but all of them return NaN.

The thing is, if I run a similar trace within `setSides()`, without using the getters - i.e. using the variables directly - they return the correct values.
And to make sure, I also did it within the function *using the getters*, so I'm sure they're the problem.

Anyone know what's going on?

EDIT: Here is my `setSides()` function:

```
public function setSides(tileSize:Number):void 
{
    var _top:Number = Math.floor(_yPos / tileSize);
    var _bottom:Number = Math.floor((_yPos + 45) / tileSize);
    var _left:Number = Math.floor(_xPos / tileSize);
    var _right:Number = Math.floor((_xPos + 20) / tileSize);

    trace("top: " + top + " bottom: " + top + " left: " + left + " right: " + right); //This gives the correct values, not NaN
}
```

But even if there was something wrong with my values I'm assigning (which would show in my trace), I've assigned a value of 0 to each of the variables in my constructor, so they shouldn't give NaN from the moment my class is instantiated.

EDIT: Oh man, I just noticed this now. Due to some testing and re-editing I did, I was still using my variables as if I was defining them (with the `var` and `:Number`). Also, the "assigning 0 to them" was also before this testing and re-editing I mentioned, so that wasn't present.

Comment: These getter looks fine. Please post the code of `setSides` and the place where you are getting correct values without using getter. May be the values are changed in some other place.

Comment: By default, they will be NaN.  Only seeing how the values are set will help to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  the "var" and the type "Number" from your "setSides()" method. Those are local variables. You're not actually setting anything. Should be:

```
    _top = Math.floor(_yPos / tileSize);
    _bottom = Math.floor((_yPos + 45) / tileSize);
    _left = Math.floor(_xPos / tileSize);
    _right = Math.floor((_xPos + 20) / tileSize);
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that as soon as I posted it. I don't know why it didn't come up with a syntax (or other type of) error though.
I've also assigned 0 to them in the constructor (see why I thought I had that in my edit above) so that I don't get any more NaN.

Comment: No problem. The default is good, so it's still a little odd why it was NaN, but perhaps it's because the "get" doesn't take default values initially, or isn't called like that.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers defaults are nan.. so:

```
private var _top:Number =0;
private var _bottom:Number =0;
private var _left:Number =0;
private var _right:Number =0;
```

and in setSides() you are setting vars with numbers inside the same class, so trace works. Try to setSides() and after that your getters works. I hope i am right 'cos i'm so sure about this :)